# Using findOne in a loop takes too long in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm using Node.js with MongoDB, I'm also using Monk for db access. I have the below code :

```
console.time("start");

collection.findOne({name: "jason"},
function(err, document) {

  for(var i = 0; i < document.friends.length; i++) // "friends is an array contains ids of the user's friends"
  {
    collection.findOne({id: document.friends[i]}, function(err, doc)
    {
      console.log(doc.name);
    });
   }

});

console.log("The file was saved!");
console.timeEnd("start");
```

I have two questions regarding this code :

1. I see the execution time and "The file was saved!" string first, then I see the names of the friends coming in the console. Why is that? Shouldn't I see the names first then the execution time? Is it because the async nature of Node.js?
2. Names are printing very slowly in the console, the speed is like one name in two seconds. Why is it so slow? Is there a way to make the process faster?

EDIT:

Is it a good idea to break friends list to smaller pieces and call friends asynchronously? Would it make the process faster?

EDIT 2:

I changed my code to this :

```
collection.find({ id: { "$in": document.friends}}).then(function(err, doc)
{
  console.log(doc.name);

      if(err) {
      return console.log(err);
       }
}
```

This doesn't give an error, but this doesn't print anything either.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your final goal means what do you want just to show friends name ?

Comment: @ShaishabRoy No, I'm printing their names just to demonstrate I can pull all friends. I will do multiple operations between them.

Comment: what type of operation do you want to perform ? it would be good if you describe clearly what do you want @json

Comment: @ShaishabRoy I'll show their names, profile information and their photos in their profile.

Comment: so you can use `aggregate` and `$lookup` to achieve this. @json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
collection.aggregate([
                                {
                                    $match:{
                                        id :{ "$in" : document.friends},
                                    }
                                }
                                ]).exec(function ( e, d ) {
                                    console.log( d )            

                                    if(!e){
                                        // your code when got data successfully
                                    }else{
                                        // your code when you got the error
                                    }    
                                });
```

Answer (score 4):

Answer for question 1: 
Yes, you are right.

Is it because the async nature of Node.js.

And to prevent that Node.js provides some mechanism for that you can use it otherwise you can do it on your own manually by setting one flag.

Answer for question 2:

you can use `$in` instead of `findOne`, it will be ease and fast.

e.g. `.find({ "fieldx": { "$in": arr } })`

`arr` :- In this you need to provide whole array.

Comment: collectionName.find({ "fieldName": { "$in": ['value1', 'value2' ] } })

Comment: I really don't understand :(

Comment: See i am taking your example so you will get the idea

Comment: document.friends is your whole array right?


collection.find({ "id": { "$in": document.friends}})

Comment: so you need to pass that  whole array and removed the for loop

Comment: Then you need to check the above findOne query which is
collection.findOne({name: "jason"} this.

it is not related this query which we discussed.

Comment: Please see my EDIT 2

Answer (score 2):

yes, it's because javascript's async nature.
As you have called db from for loop javascript will not wait for it's response and continue the execution so it will print the file was saved first.

about your ans 2
It's making a dbCall for every friend then it's obvious that it will take some time that's why it's taking 1 or 2 secs for every friend.

```
console.time("start");

collection.findOne({name: "jason"},
function(err, document) {

  for(var i = 0; i < document.friends.length; i++) // "friends is an array contains ids of the user's friends"
  {
    console.log("InsideforLoop Calling " + i + " friend");
    collection.findOne({id: document.friends[i]}, function(err, doc)
    {
      console.log(doc.name);
    });
    console.log("Terminating " + i + "-----");
   }

});

console.log("The file was saved!");
console.timeEnd("start");
```

This will make your async and db doubts more clear.
As you will see it will print all console in line.

> InsideforLoop Calling 0 friend
>
> Terminating 0 -----

and so on....Like this

> console.log(doc.name);
>
> but this will be printed asynchronusly

**Added**

```
collection.findOne({name: "jason"},
function(err, document) {

      //you can do this
      collection.find({id: $in:{document.friends}, function(err, doc)
        {
          console.log(doc);
        });

});
```

> Find All Details in one call

Comment: Is there a way to make those `findOne` calls faster?

Comment: I dont think you can do this but you can change your approch you can take all the details in one dbCall.

Comment: It depends on you which approch you take but you can not reduce time for dbCall

Comment: You mean taking all db once?

Comment: no but taking all details at once I mean if you want a user with it's friends you can get all details of them at the same time.

Comment: @jason have updated my answer you can use that approch

Answer (score 1):

```
collection.findOne({name: "jason"},
function(err, document) {

if(document != undefined){
    collection.find({ id: { "$in": document.friends}}).then(function(err, doc)
{
  console.log(doc.name);

      if(err) {
      return console.log(err);
       }
}
}
});
```

Comment: Nothing changed, `document` is not `undefined` either.

Comment: sorry i dont get you

Comment: you are able to see the console which you printed?

Comment: I mean this code didn't change anything, it's not printing anything. And document is defined and yes I am able to see the console, but it's not printing any output.

Comment: Just do one thing

Comment: see the document.friends and write it like this

[document.friends]

and check.

Comment: I did, it's full. I think I need to do something else as well.

Comment: It's not printing anything because it's still working on the query?

Comment: I'm using monk for db access, do you think would that be a problem?

Comment: mmhhhh, May be because i have no idea about it.

Comment: What are you using for db access? Mongoose?

Comment: I wrote `console.log("Hello world")` inside the inner callback function, but it's not even printing that... Does that mean it's still working on the query?

Answer (score 0):

Answer to 1: Yes, it is because node is async. The part where it logs names is executed only when the first `findOne` returns, whereas `the file was saved` is executed straight away.