# collection.find() does not work as expected - Node.js and MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Below code is supposed to print names of the friends of a user :

```
collection.findOne({name: "jason"},
function(err, document) {

collection.find({ id: { "$in": document.friends}}).then(function(err, doc)
{
  console.log(doc.name);

      if(err) {
      return console.log(err);
       }

    })

});
```

I'm 100% sure that document is not undefined. I can log info of the document, but it doesn't print any information of friends. There is no error either. It just waits. Can you tell me where the problem is? Thanks.

EDIT :
My user looks like this :

```
{
  "id": 22448856945,
  "id_str": "224488456945",
  "name": "jason",
  "friends" : [954962638965, 3212489563163, 1659795263231]
}
```

Comment: The question is "What does `document.freinds` look like?"` `$in` would be expecting an array of `ObjectId` in this case. You need to show us what the document actually looks like.

Comment: @NeilLunn as you said, `document.freinds` is an array of ids of jason's friends

Comment: Can you please show us an example. And at least one document that should match. It's possibly `_id` and not `id`, but mongoose should be aliasing this and not care. Is this mongoose? Or just the plain node driver? If it's the plain driver then it makes a lot of difference.

Comment: So the behavior basically boils down to "mongoose" vs "node native driver". But instead you should be clarifying this point with the people who [already answered your existing question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45189606/using-findone-in-a-loop-takes-too-long-in-node-js). You had this same code posted there for the duration of all the responses. Please clear it up with them instead of posting new questions.

Comment: @NeilLunn I'm using Monk, do you think would that be problem?

Comment: I think you should pay attention to your existing question you asked before this one. Tell the people who answered you there that you are using monk and any problems with the solutions they gave you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collection.find will return an array of result. Try console.log(doc[0].name). You will have to loop over the results.

Comment: Well kind of. If it's actually "mongoose" then it returns an array of results. If it's actually the plain node driver, then it returns something else entirely. So actually waiting on the OP to respond to that very question. But. They also duplicated their existing question.